# Add to Model one by one after Looping C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a code like:

```
var subQuerytrue = from trd in _context.TrdSbphtms
                   where trd.Sell == false && trd.TrdOhDp == request.KodeDp
                   group trd by trd.TrdOhKode into g
                   select new { TRD_OH_Kode = g.Key, SisaNominal = g.Sum(x => x.SisaNominal) };

var equery = (from a in subQuerytrue
         join mobl in _context.Mobls on a.TRD_OH_Kode equals mobl.MoblCode into moblGroup
         from m in moblGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
         where m.MoblMaturityDate > td
         select new 
         {
             PIHAK = m.MoblIssuer ?? "",
             NAMAINVESTASI = a.TRD_OH_Kode ?? "",
             TGLJATUHTEMPO = m.MoblMaturityDate,
             SUKUBUNGA = m.MoblInterest ?? 0,
             HARIDIAKUI = m.MoblJangka * 30,
             HARITAHUN = 360,
             JANGKA = m.MoblJangka ?? 0,
             TGLTERBIT = m.MoblIssuedDate,
             TGLBUNGA = m.MoblTanggalBunga ?? 0,
             SISANOMINAL = a.SisaNominal ?? 0,
             MOBLCODE = m.MoblCode ?? ""
         }).ToList();

if (equery.Any())
{
    foreach (var item in equery)
    {
        jangka = item.JANGKA;
        DateTime defaultDate = new(2000, 1, 1);
        DateTime? ptgljthtempo = item.TGLJATUHTEMPO;
        DateTime? ptglterbit = item.TGLTERBIT;
        int? ptglbunga = item.TGLBUNGA;
        double? psisanominal = item.SISANOMINAL;
        string? pnamainvestasi = item.NAMAINVESTASI;
        string? MOBLCODE = item.MOBLCODE;

        int monthsDifference = ((ptgljthtempo ?? defaultDate).Year - (ptglterbit ?? defaultDate).Year) * 12 + (ptgljthtempo ?? defaultDate).Month - (ptgljthtempo ?? defaultDate).Month;
        max_pay = monthsDifference / jangka;

        if (ptglterbit != null)
        {
            int monthsDiff = ((td.Year - ptglterbit.Value.Year) * 12) + td.Month - ptglterbit.Value.Month;
            if (monthsDifference % jangka == 0)
            {
                bayar_ke = monthsDiff / jangka;
            }
            else
            {
                bayar_ke = 0;
            }
        }

        if (bayar_ke > 0)
        {
            if (ptglbunga != null)
            {
                DateTime targetDate = new((request.Periode ?? defaultDate).Year, (request.Periode ?? defaultDate).Month, (int)ptglbunga);

                var rs3 = (from trd in _context.TrdSbphtmSells where trd.TglBeli > targetDate && trd.TrdOhKode == MOBLCODE select trd.Nominal).Sum();
                bnghitung = jangka * (int)ptglbunga * ((psisanominal ?? 0) - (rs3 > 0 ? rs3.Value ?? 0 : 0)) / 1200;
                bng = 0;
                tglbunga = new DateTime((request.PeriodTo ?? defaultDate).Year, (request.PeriodTo ?? defaultDate).Month, (int)ptglbunga);
                Nom = 0;

                var rs3true = (from trd in _context.TrdSbphtms where trd.TglBeli > tglbunga && trd.TrdOhKode == pnamainvestasi
                               group trd by 1 into g select new { a = g.Sum(x => x.SisaNominal), b = g.Sum(x => x.Nominal) }).FirstOrDefault();

                Nom = rs3true?.a ?? 0;

                var rs4true = (from trd in _context.TrdSbphtmSells where trd.TglBeli > tglbunga && trd.TrdOhKode == pnamainvestasi
                               group trd by 1 into g select new { a = g.Sum(x => x.SisaNominal), b = g.Sum(x => x.Nominal) }).FirstOrDefault();

                Nom += rs4true?.a ?? 0;

                if (bnghitung > 0)
                {
                    var detailquery = equery.Select(s => new
                    {
                        s.PIHAK,
                        s.NAMAINVESTASI,
                        TGLJATUHTEMPO = tglbunga,
                        NILAINOMINAL = (psisanominal - Nom) == 0 ? rs4true?.b * -1 : psisanominal - Nom,
                        s.SUKUBUNGA,
                        s.HARIDIAKUI,
                        s.HARITAHUN,
                        BUNGAHITUNG = bnghitung,
                        BUNGAREAL = bng,
                        TANGGALTERIMA = tglbunga,
                        Keterangan = bayar_ke + " dari " + max_pay
                    });

                    // DETAIL
                    model.ReportBungaRealSBPDetails = detailquery.Where(w => w.BUNGAHITUNG > 0).Select(s => new ReportBungaRealSBPDetail
                    {
                        PIHAK = s.PIHAK,
                        NAMAINVESTASI = s.NAMAINVESTASI,
                        TGLJATUHTEMPO = s.TGLJATUHTEMPO,
                        NILAINOMINAL = s.NILAINOMINAL,
                        SUKUBUNGA = s.SUKUBUNGA,
                        HARIDIAKUI = s.HARIDIAKUI,
                        HARITAHUN = s.HARITAHUN,
                        BUNGAHITUNG = s.BUNGAHITUNG,
                        BUNGAREAL = s.BUNGAREAL,
                        TANGGALTERIMA = s.TANGGALTERIMA,
                        Keterangan = s.Keterangan
                    }).ToList();
                }
            }                            
        }
    }
}
```

The result should be only 2 records which is bnghitung > 0.
My question is, when I debug. The model.ReportBungaRealSBPDetails is getting all the result of equery, which is 39 records. and the 'bnghitung' is become the same for all the records.
Why? I want to add into a model.ReportBungaRealSBPDetails only if the criteria meets. Is there anything wrong on the code above?

Need advice please.
Thank you.

Comment: The very fact you wrote that wall of code should tell you this is wrong. Very wrong. EF is an ORM, not a database driver or an embedded SQL dialect. The job of all ORMs is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables and rows. It's *EF's* job, not the developer's to load the objects involved in a query, *along* with any related objects, based on the configured relations. There's rarely any reason to use JOIN like this. What you load are objects, not tables and rows and the names should reflect that. `Mobls` isn't the name of a class. `PIHAK` isn't the name of a property

Comment: You don't need to check if a collection has `.Any()` items before you `foreach` it,by the way; foreach simply doesn't run on an empty collection. If youre working with some legacy DB that has horrible short table and column names like TrdSbphtms, you might like to make your C# life easier by giving a full name to the entity collection/entity property in C# and then telling EF that the `TurdSubstitutingPhantoms` DbSet refers to the TrdSbphtms table using the `[Table("TrdSbphtms")]` attribute or similar in the fluent builder.. (And same for `[Column("ClmnNm")]` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is how I see it:

You go into this if when bnghitung, which you calculated a couple lines previously,
is > 0. But then you fill your detailquery with EVERY instance contained in your equery and
give every instance the SAME value. Meaning that all records IN detailquery fit the condition for bnghitung > 0.

Here Im including the code space I think went wrong.

```
if (bnghitung > 0)
{
    var detailquery = equery.Select(s => new
    {
        s.PIHAK,
        s.NAMAINVESTASI,
        TGLJATUHTEMPO = tglbunga,
        NILAINOMINAL = (psisanominal - Nom) == 0 ? rs4true?.b * -1 : psisanominal - Nom,
        s.SUKUBUNGA,
        s.HARIDIAKUI,
        s.HARITAHUN,
        BUNGAHITUNG = bnghitung, //this is the issue
        BUNGAREAL = bng,
        TANGGALTERIMA = tglbunga,
        Keterangan = bayar_ke + " dari " + max_pay
    });

    // DETAIL
    model.ReportBungaRealSBPDetails = detailquery.Where(w => w.BUNGAHITUNG > 0).Select(s => new ReportBungaRealSBPDetail
    {
        PIHAK = s.PIHAK,
        NAMAINVESTASI = s.NAMAINVESTASI,
        TGLJATUHTEMPO = s.TGLJATUHTEMPO,
        NILAINOMINAL = s.NILAINOMINAL,
        SUKUBUNGA = s.SUKUBUNGA,
        HARIDIAKUI = s.HARIDIAKUI,
        HARITAHUN = s.HARITAHUN,
        BUNGAHITUNG = s.BUNGAHITUNG,
        BUNGAREAL = s.BUNGAREAL,
        TANGGALTERIMA = s.TANGGALTERIMA,
        Keterangan = s.Keterangan
    }).ToList();
}
```

Ok since you need too loop through every item anyways it doesnt make sense to always create the List fot the model
so this is my suggestion for a fix

```
if (bnghitung > 0)
{
    ReportBungaRealSBPDetail detail = new ReportBungaRealSBPDetail()
    {
        PIHAK = item.PIHAK,
        NAMAINVESTASI = pnamainvestasi,
        TGLJATUHTEMPO = tglbunga,
        NILAINOMINAL = (psisanominal - Nom) == 0 ? rs4true?.b * -1 : psisanominal - Nom,
        SUKUBUNGA = item.SUKUBUNGA,
        HARIDIAKUI = item.HARIDIAKUI,
        HARITAHUN = item.HARITAHUN,
        BUNGAHITUNG = bnghitung,
        BUNGAREAL = bng,
        TANGGALTERIMA = tglbunga,
        Keterangan = bayar_ke + " dari " + max_pay
    }
                    
    model.ReportBungaRealSBPDetails.Add(detail);
}
```